# Active Storage not resizing images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I am using active storage on rails 5.2.4 with the gems:

```
# Use ActiveStorage variant
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 0.2.3'
```

and trying with

```
    <%= image_tag photo.image.variant(resize: "1000x1000").processed.service_url, class: 'img-responsive-full' %>
```

```
    <%= image_tag photo.image.variant(resize: "1000x1000>").processed.service_url, class: 'img-responsive-full' %>
```

```
    <%= image_tag photo.image.variant(resize: "1000>x1000>").processed.service_url, class: 'img-responsive-full' %>
```

none of these methods is resizing the images or forcing the 1000x1000 dimensions I want, how could I force the images to be that size? (I have just migrated from paperclip to active storage)

Comment: According to the API documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-image it states that you're not supposed to be processing them inline. I'd try triggering the process in the controller or define the variants in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `!` got it working:

```
<%= image_tag photo.image.variant(resize: "1000x1000!"), class: 'img-responsive-full' %>
```

Although I can not find an explanation on why was not resizing without it. By reading the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-image) seems like it should work without any addition.